# Prevent Modal Rerendering when only Modal Content Change: React Hooks useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-reducer

I have a parent-child component **Modal** and **ModalContent** in my React App both functional.

1) I have created an AppContext in App.js for accessing it globally in all components.

`const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {modalOpen: false, content: []});`

```
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }} >
      //BrowserRouter and Routes Definition
    </App>
```

Here **reducer** is a fairly plain function with toggle for **modalOpen** and push/pop functionality in **content**(array).

2) My `Modal` Component makes use of

```
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext); 
<Modal open={state.modalOpen} />
```

to get the state of modal visibility to set it open/closed.

3) My `ModalContent` Component makes use of

```
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext); 
<ModalContent data={state.content} />
  //Dispatch from the `ModalContent`
  dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CONTENT', data: 'newata' });
```

4) Here is my reducer.

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_MODAL':
            return {...state, modalOpen: !state.modalOpen};
    case 'UPDATE_CONTENT':
        return { ...state, content: [...state.content, action.data]};
    default:
        return {modalOpen: false,content: []};
 }
}
```

I have set up some code in `ModalContent` to update the data `content` property using dispatch and the reducer store is updated perfectly and returns fresh/updated:

```
 {modalOpen: true/false, content: updatedContentArray}
```

**The issue is**: Whenever I dispatch an action via `ModalContent` complete state is returned(expected), by the reducer and Modal reopens itself as it listens to state.modalOpen.

**Unsuccessful Attempt**: I attempted to specifically pull required properties in respective components. But the `Modal` component still rerenders even when just content is changed. Is there any way to watch for specific state only

**How can make this work by rerendering only `ModalContent` not `Modal`.**

**Edit: Updated question with my mock(working) reducer code and dispatch statement from the ModalContent itself.**

Comment: can you show your reducer and the dispatch call. Also is the issue just that Modal is re-rendering or that the openModal is incorrectly getting modelOpen value as true

Comment: You could enhance `Modal` with `React.memo` to be a memoized component, which won't re-render, if `state.modalOpen` has the same value.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have added my simpler version of my reducer(working) and added a dispatch call in the code snippet above. The openModal is working fine as I can see when I close the modal it closes and state updates to false for that.

Comment: ok, so the issue is just the re-rendering of Modal component when only content changes?

Comment: Yes @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason both `Modal` and `ModalContent` get re-rendered when Content changes is because both the components make use of the same context and when a context value changes all components listening to the context are re-rendered

A way to fix this re-rendering thing is to make use of `multiple contexts` like

```
 const modalContextVal = useMemo(() => ({ modalOpen: state.modalOpen, dispatch}), [state.modalOpen]);
   const contentContextVal = useMemo(() => ({ content: state.content, dispatch}), [state.content]);
   ....
   <ModalContext.Provider value={modalContextVal}>
      <ContentContext.Provider value={contentContextVal}>
      //BrowserRouter and Routes Definition
      </ContentContext.Provider>
    </ModalContext.Provider>
```

And use it like

In Modal.js

```
const {modalOpen, dispatch} = useContext(ModalContext);
```

In ModalContent.js

```
const {content, dispatch} = useContext(ContentContext);
```

Comment: Perfect @shubham, worked like a charm in fact with this approach I can even access multiple contexts in a single component(if needed) without worrying about rerendering until I specifically update that piece of state!

Answer (score 1):

As @Shubham said you have to keep modal state and modal content separate.

It can be done with separate context or even simple useState

**Example snippet**

```js
const { useReducer, createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect, memo, useMemo } = React;

const AppContext = createContext();

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if(action.type == 'toggleModal') {
    return {
      ...state,
      modalOpen: !state.modalOpen
    }
  }
  
  return state;
}

const AppContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {modalOpen: false, content: [{id: 1, value: 'test'}]});

  return <AppContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
    {children}
  </AppContext.Provider>
}

const Modal = ({children, modalOpen}) => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext); 

  console.log('Render Modal');

  return <div className={`modal ${modalOpen ? 'modal--open': null}`}>
    {children}
  </div>
}

const ModalContent = ({data, onClick}) => {

  console.log('Render Modal Content');
  
  return <div className="modal__content">
    {data.map(({id, value}) => <div className="item" key={id}>{value}</div>)}
    <button onClick={onClick} className="modal__close">Close</button>
  </div>
}

const App = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext); 
  const { modalOpen, } = state;
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
  
  const onClick = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'toggleModal' });
  }

  return <div>
    <Modal modalOpen={modalOpen}>
      {useMemo(() => {
  
  console.log('render useMemo');
  
  return <ModalContent onClick={onClick} data={content}></ModalContent>
  }, [content])}
    </Modal>
    <button onClick={onClick}>Open Modal</button>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AppContextProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
.modal {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.modal__close {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal--open {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```